# NServiceBus unable to receive message

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus5

I'm following the NServiceBus getting started guide (version 5) and I get the below error.

When the client sends a command to the server, the server has issues to receive the message. The code is okay, because the exact same code on another machine is working. So something is missing on my machine.

I did run this command as is mentioned in the tutorial:

> DISM.exe /Online /NoRestart /English /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:MSMQ-Server

But it's still not working.

> 2016-11-01 19:50:47.316 ERROR
>   ServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy Error in receiving messages.
>       System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The Transaction Manager is not available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D01B) 
>       at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ConnectToProxy(String nodeName, Guid resourceManagerIdentifier, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Boolean& nodeName Matches, UInt32& whereaboutsSize, CoTaskMemHandle& whereaboutsBuffer, IResourceManagerShim& resourceManagerShim)
>       at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at system.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMExcept
>   ion comException)
>       at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()
>       at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.get_ProxyShimFactory()
>       at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.CreateTransaction(Transa
>   ctionOptions properties)
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromoted.EnterState(InternalTransactio
>   n tx)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction(In
>   ternalTransaction tx)
>      at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
>      at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transacti
>   on transaction)
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction trans
>   action)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int3
>   2 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback rece
>   iveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 actio
>   n, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction in
>   ternalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive(TimeSpan timeout, MessageQueueTransa
>   ctionType transactionType)
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.b__12_1() in C:\Bu
>   ildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueS
>   trategy.cs:line 248
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.TryReceiveMessage(Func`1 r
>   eceive, Message& message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus
>   .Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the issue was that the service Distributed Transaction Coordinator was turned off. After turning it on everything works as expected.