# ERROR NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy - Error in receiving messages

Tags: c#, nservicebus, msmq, msdtc

Event Viewer on my workstation have the following error log:

> ERROR NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy [(null)] - Error in receiving messages.
>   System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The Transaction Manager is not available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D01B)
>      at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ConnectToProxy(String nodeName, Guid resourceManagerIdentifier, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Boolean& nodeNameMatches, UInt32& whereaboutsSize, CoTaskMemHandle& whereaboutsBuffer, IResourceManagerShim& resourceManagerShim)
>      at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException comException)
>      at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.Initialize()
>      at System.Transactions.Oletx.DtcTransactionManager.get_ProxyShimFactory()
>      at System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.CreateTransaction(TransactionOptions properties)
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromoted.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction(InternalTransaction tx)
>      at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
>      at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive(TimeSpan timeout, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
>      at NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.MsmqDequeueStrategy.TryReceiveMessage(Func`1 receive, Message& message) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3206e2123f54fce4\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\Msmq\MsmqDequeueStrategy.cs:line 332

#### Facts:

- Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) Component Service ==> [DTC Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbK7c.png)
- Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) Service ==> Running (referenced to [Answered Stack Oveflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366959/nservicebus-unable-to-receive-message))
- Realtek Audio Universal Service ==> Disabled (as per reference in  [Fix for 0x8004d01b](https://discuss.particular.net/t/help-diagnose-problem-with-msdtc-the-transaction-manager-is-not-available-exception-from-hresult-0x8004d01b/875/9))

Can anyone recommend a direction on how to check/troubleshoot the cause of the issue?

Comment: The DTC is needed because both MSMQ and some other service are participating in the transaction. What other service is involved? SQL Server? Did you verify that you can run a DTC transaction between the two machines in question, with the DTC ping tool?

Comment: From my experience, this has _always_ been a firewall issue. Make sure DTC ping is working in both directions between the involved servers, before you try to actually do something with NServiceBus or MSMQ.

Comment: @gnud It also involved SQL Server as we processed message in the queue and stored to the database. How can I verify that MSMQ and SQLServer were interacting/participating in a DTC Transaction?

DTC has been allowed for (Domain, Private, and Public for the sake of test) but still the same.

Comment: As I said - ignore NServiceBus, MSMQ and SQL Server until you can run DTC ping between the servers successfully. DTC ping is a small utility that lets you debug DTC connection issues. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918331/how-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues-in-ms-dtc-by-using-the-dtcping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long ardous hours, the issue I encountered boils down to permission issue. The services involved in DTC which uses credentials of LocalSystem do not have enough permission and blocked by company-imposed policy implemented on the server.

Unfortunately, I only managed to find an alternative or workaround by using account that have enough permissions to operate and manage the services involved (including custom services).

@gnud - Thanks a lot for your inputs giving me a direction for investigation and that help me continue move forward on my investigation. I appreciate the help. Thanks.